# Can a app developed in iOS Enterprise program be distributed in app store with a different iOS Standard Program?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have a question in the Apple Developer Programs and their distribution.

I have a Enterprise Developer program and have to develop an iOS app, but the distribution to the app store has to be done by a Customer.

My Customer already have a different Standard developer program to distribute to Apps store.
Since both the ownership of Developer Programs are different, is it possible to distribute the apps in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Answer seems late, but it might help future readers

You have developed an app and have tested it on device(s) using iOS Enterprise program ($299). You can always send the code to the customer who can sign it using iOS Developer program ($99) and upload it to the AppStore.
The core point to understand here is that developing an app is different from signing it.